# Best way of using Kafka streams for different processes withing single app

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I want to implement mirroring mechanism between kafka brokers and find kafka streams as a good solution for it.

But for now I have one question open: should I use single kafka streams object for all topics I want to mirror, or it's better to create separate instance per each topic.

2nd approach has several advantages, all mirroring processes will be loose coupled, and if one fails others will work. Also each mirroring could be configured differently, which is nice. It won't use single threadpool for all topics, loaded and not that loaded. Although it has obvious drowback - I should use dedicated application.id for each process.

So what is the best way from kafka streams concept perspective? Since amount of topics which should be mirrored could be 100+ with high load on each.

EDIT: question is not about mirroring solution, but best way of using kafka streams for different processes withing same app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the key differences in existent approaches to mirror Kafka topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333860/whats-the-key-differences-in-existent-approaches-to-mirror-kafka-topics)

Comment: Mirroring? Do you mean from one cluster into another? That's not possible with Kafka Streams, because Kafka Streams can only connect to one cluster.

Comment: Yes, it is,so I'm using processor with plain KafkaProducer<>.

Comment: You should rather use MirrorMaker or similar tool to cross-cluster replication. The pattern you use is not recommended.

Comment: How is the question "not about mirroring solution"? When you said "mirror" 5 times before the edit?

Comment: **mirroring** means between *distinct clusters* in Kafka terms. If you're simply using Streams on the *same cluster*, there's no need to distinguish "between brokers" because Streams natively partitions data in that way. Buts that's just filtering, mapping, joining, etc, not "mirroring"

Comment: MirrorMaker is console tool and logic of that tool not that obvious to modify in future. I've chosen streams + plain producer solution for this task. 
So question is not about solution of the task (I've already chose one) but about the way I should use kafka streams, singe KStream object for all topics, or dedicated KStreams object per topic.